# Python, Regular Expression help. Insert with re

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to know how to convert this string:

> v10:2:34:5h101111gV5H2p1

to this:

> ;v10:2:34:5;h101111;gV5H2;p1;

So in words, I want to know how to insert ';' before all lowercase letters.  I can just add the ';' at end with:

```
str = str + ';'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your string is in variable `x`:

```
import re
re.sub('([a-z]|$)', r';\1', x)
```

Comment: that also gets the end-of-string case

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s
'v10:2:34:5h101111gV5H2p1'
>>> ''.join(';'+x if x.islower() else x for x in s)+';'
';v10:2:34:5;h101111;gV5H2;p1;'
```

Answer (score 2):

a non-`regex` approach:

```
In [11]: from string import ascii_lowercase

In [12]: strs="v10:2:34:5h101111gV5H2p1"

In [13]: ''.join(';'+x if x in ascii_lowercase else x for x in strs)+';'
Out[13]: ';v10:2:34:5;h101111;gV5H2;p1;'
```

or:

```
In [16]: ''.join(';'+x if x.lower()==x and x.isalpha() else x for x in strs)+';'

out[16]: ';v10:2:34:5;h101111;gV5H2;p1;'
```

Comment: no it's not deprecated, and I've to use both `x.lower()==x and x.isalpha()`.

Comment: `'10'.islower()` is `False` @ Ashwini, so no need to do `.isalpha()`

Comment: I think `x.islower()` works better than `x.lower()==x` for this. It only fires for "cased" characters which means it should include your `isalpha` check already.